# R - how to calculate derivatives of two-dimensional discrete function?

Tags: r, differentiation

I have two-dimensional discrete function - actually a 3D-surface defined in two variables. This surface is built by another program and as a result I have huge array of `(X, Y, Z)` points in my datafile. It can be successfully plot with `ggplot` and that's fine.

But now I should find all stationary points on these surface - maxima, minima and saddles. I know that such task could be easily solved with the help of first- and second-order partial derivatives criteria but I have no idea how to implement it in practice.

As for me I think that the obvious way is to walk through my surface in both directions, compute numerical derivatives and then test values obtained against zero (with some tolerance). I've found `numDeriv` package for R but it seems that it wants `func` object as real-valued function while I have only discrete set of points.

So I wonder if there are any other suggestions, better approaches or may be even ready-to-use packages to solve such task? Thank you!

Comment: If I understand this correctly, you do not have a function but an array of function values? If so, your problem seems a little bigger than "need an R function". I would look into iterative methods for optimization such as [Hill Climbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_climbing) to find local maxima or minima.
Then maybe consider something a bit faster than R.

Comment: Requests such as these need a data object for testing and demonstration. They also need some evidence of having searched for an SO duplicate.

Comment: @Croote, yes, you're right. The only thing that I have is just dataframe with three columns - for `X`, `Y` and `Z`. I've thought about local optimization methods, but this won't reveal any saddles for me, am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, finally I solved it (not the best solution, but it could help someone anyway). I decided to start with numerical differentiation (central differences) and not to use local spline/polynomial fitting as **@42-** suggested.

```
# our dataset consists of points (x, y, z), where z = f(x, y)

z_dx <- function(x, y) { # first partial derivative dz/dx
    pos_x <- which(df_x == x)

    if (pos_x == 1 | pos_x == length(df_x)) return(NA)

    xf <- df_x[pos_x + 1]
    xb <- df_x[pos_x - 1]

    return((df[which(df$x == xf & df$y == y), "z"] - df[which(df$x == xb & df$y == y), "z"]) / (xf - xb))
}

z_dy <- function(x, y) { # first partial derivative dz/dy
    pos_y <- which(df_y == y)

    if (pos_y == 1 | pos_y == length(df_y)) return(NA)

    yf <- df_y[pos_y + 1]
    yb <- df_y[pos_y - 1]

    return((df[which(df$y == yf & df$x == x), "z"] - df[which(df$y == yb & df$x == x), "z"]) / (yf - yb))
}

z_dx2 <- function(x, y) { # second partial derivative d2z/dx2
    pos_x <- which(df_x == x)

    if (pos_x <= 2 | pos_x >= (length(df_x) - 1)) return(NA)

    xf <- df_x[pos_x + 1]
    xb <- df_x[pos_x - 1]

    return((df[which(df$x == xf & df$y == y), "dx"] - df[which(df$x == xb & df$y == y), "dx"]) / (xf - xb))
}

z_dy2 <- function(x, y) { # second partial derivative d2z/dy2
    pos_y <- which(df_y == y)

    if (pos_y <= 2 | pos_y >= (length(df_y) - 1)) return(NA)

    yf <- df_y[pos_y + 1]
    yb <- df_y[pos_y - 1]

    return((df[which(df$y == yf & df$x == x), "dy"] - df[which(df$y == yb & df$x == x), "dy"]) / (yf - yb))
}

z_dxdy <- function(x, y) { # second partial derivative d2z/dxdy
    pos_y <- which(df_y == y)

    if (pos_y <= 2 | pos_y >= (length(df_y) - 1)) return(NA)

    yf <- df_y[pos_y + 1]
    yb <- df_y[pos_y - 1]

    return((df[which(df$y == yf & df$x == x), "dx"] - df[which(df$y == yb & df$x == x), "dx"]) / (yf - yb))
}

# read dataframe and set proper column names
df <- read.table("map.dat", header = T)
names(df) <- c("x", "y", "z")

# extract unique abscissae
df_x <- unique(df$x)
df_y <- unique(df$y)

# calculate first derivatives numerically
df$dx <- apply(df, 1, function(x) z_dx(x["x"], x["y"]))
df$dy <- apply(df, 1, function(x) z_dy(x["x"], x["y"]))

# set tolerance limits, so we can filter out every non-stationary point later
tolerance_x <- 30.0
tolerance_y <- 10.0

# select only stationary points
df$stat <- apply(df, 1, function(x) ifelse(is.na(x["dx"]) | is.na(x["dy"]), FALSE, ifelse(abs(x["dx"]) <= tolerance_x & abs(x["dy"]) <= tolerance_y, TRUE, FALSE)))
stationaries <- df[which(df$stat == TRUE), ]

# compute second derivatives for selected points
stationaries$dx2 <- apply(stationaries, 1, function(x) z_dx2(x["x"], x["y"]))
stationaries$dy2 <- apply(stationaries, 1, function(x) z_dy2(x["x"], x["y"]))
stationaries$dxdy <- apply(stationaries, 1, function(x) z_dxdy(x["x"], x["y"]))

# let's make classifying function...
stat_type <- function(dx2, dy2, dxdy) {
    if (is.na(dx2) | is.na(dy2) | is.na(dxdy)) return("unk")
    if (dx2 * dy2 - dxdy^2 < 0) return("saddle")
    if (dx2 * dy2 - dxdy^2 > 0) {
        if (dx2 < 0 & dy2 < 0) return("max")
        else if (dx2 > 0 & dy2 > 0) return("min")
        else return("unk")
    }
    else return("unk")
}

# ...and apply it to our stationary points
stationaries$type <- apply(stationaries, 1, function(x) stat_type(x["dx2"], x["dy2"], x["dxdy"]))
stationaries <- stationaries[which(stationaries$type != "unk"), ] # leave out all non-stationarities

# set upper cutoff (in the units of z = f(x, y)) - points with the greatest value of z can form very large areas where derivatives are so close to zero that we can't discriminate them (this is often the case when our map is built by numerical integration with predefined grid so final result is discrete function of two variables)
cutwidth <- 2.5
stationaries <- stationaries[which(stationaries$z <= (max(stationaries$z) - cutwidth)), ] # select only points which are lying below maximum by selected cutoff

# create dataframes for minima, maxima and saddles
minima <- stationaries[which(stationaries$type == "min"), ]
maxima <- stationaries[which(stationaries$type == "max"), ]
saddles <- stationaries[which(stationaries$type == "saddle"), ]
```

Things becomes easier if your map have constant grid size - then there is no need to calculate stepsize for differentiation for every point

Answer (score 0):

Searching on Rhelp, I found a similar question (although not quite as broad). It just asked for find local maxima, but generalizing to the other cases shouldn't be too difficult. The questioner supplied a dataset:

```
require(MASS)
topo.lo <- loess(z ~ x * y, topo, degree = 1, span = 0.25,
                 normalize = FALSE)
topo.mar <- list(x = seq(0, 6.5, 0.1), y = seq(0, 6.5, 0.1))
new.dat <- expand.grid(topo.mar)
topo.pred <- predict(topo.lo, new.dat)
## draw the contour map based on loess predictions


library(rgl)


persp3d(topo.mar$x, topo.mar$y, topo.pred, shade=0.5, col="blue")
```

And got this answer (which admittedly doesn't specifically calculate derivatives, but then numerical derivatives are just first differences), which is what this test is using:

```
hasmax <- function(mtx, x, y)  if(  (mtx[x,y] > mtx[x,y-1]) &
                                    (mtx[x,y] > mtx[x,y+1]) &
                                    (mtx[x,y] > mtx[x-1,y]) &
                         (mtx[x,y] > mtx[x+1,y]) ) {return(TRUE ) } else {return(FALSE)}


for(i in 3:(dim(topo.pred)[1] -4)) {
    for(j in 3:(dim(topo.pred)[2]-4) )  {
        if( hasmax(topo.pred, i , j) ){print(c(topo.mar$x[i],topo.mar$y[j]))}  }}
```

I'm posting it with only a minor change, because it was my answer :-)

I'm thinking there might be packages out there that deal with spatial datasets, but I'm not  particularly familiar so you might want to search CRAN Task Views.

Comment: Hmm... seems like interpolation of surface with something looks great. As minimum, I can fed it for any derivative calculation function.

Thank you for illustration, I think that I can play around with and test results!

Comment: Interpolation of 2d data that is not on a regular grid to start with is sometimes handled with loess2d or akima::akima or kriging

Comment: my grid data is actually evenly spaced so this is not a problem